# Error while merging dex archives: com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory

Tags: android, react-native, android-glide

I added native android code to RN app, able to run debug app but while creating release build getting mergeDex error. I am using multidex also still i am getting this issue.

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'

@GlideModule
class GlideAppModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder)
        builder.apply { RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) }
    }
}
```

> Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED
> ERROR:android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex: D8: Type com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory is defined multiple times: /android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex, //android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes2.dex
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory is defined multiple times: /Users//android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex, /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes2.dex
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:128)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
> /android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex: D8: Type com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory is defined multiple times: /android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex, /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes2.dex

```
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:111)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:760)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex
at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.2.66.java:0)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:89)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:113)
... 36 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory is defined multiple times: /android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex, /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes2.dex
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.V0.a(SourceFile:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.V0.a(SourceFile:25)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.b(SourceFile:6)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory is defined multiple times: /android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex, /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes2.dex

```
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:24)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:10)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:6)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.i1$c.e(SourceFile:3)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(SourceFile:336)
at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(SourceFile:265)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(D8.java:22)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:6)
at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:47)
... 38 more
```

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
> Type com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedRequestManagerFactory is defined multiple times: //android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.dex, /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes2.dex

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, when I upgrade my porject 64.2 to 69.7.

Wait for help!

I can bundle to real device, but only failed on generate bundle realease .aab

Comment: try this  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).